# Можно ли как-то задать время жизни переменных в localestorage?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Я так понимаю, что в localstorage переменные не ограничены по времени жизни?
А можно ли как-то его задать принудительно?
Что случится, если один сайт полностью заполнит все доступное ему место?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#disk-space

> User agents may prompt the user when quotas are reached, allowing the user to grant a site more space. This enables sites to store many user-created documents on the user's computer, for instance.

> User agents should allow users to see how much space each domain is using.

Comment: принудительно, как и в sql, просто очищайте время от времени старые объекты.

Comment: Мне почему то кажется что если время жизни - то это куки.